# Testing module for measuring time of function

Tags: python

**Hello everyone.**

I wrote my own test module, which is responsible for measuring the timing of algorithms, I used it mainly for sorting algorithms this is so to say a very early beta version, which I would like to expand with various functionalities, in general I would like to take care of the appearance of the code. I look forward to your opinions and comments, possibly your own ideas.

So here is my testing_module code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

accident = ["x", "random.randint(1, 100)", "x"]
history = ["Optimistic", "Average", "Pessimistic"]

def make_data(numbers, y):
    data = []
    for element in numbers:
        data.append([eval(accident[y]) for x in range(element)])
    return data

def make_plot(numbers, measures, name):
    for x in range(3):
        plt.plot(numbers, measures[x], label = history[x])
    plt.title(name)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def test(method, numbers, measures):
    name_function = method.__name__
    for x in range(3):
        if x != 2:
            for element in make_data(numbers, x):
                method(element, x)
        else:
            for element in make_data(numbers, x):
                element.reverse()
                method(element, x)
                
    make_plot(numbers, measures, name_function)
```

And this is how i was using it in my code:

```
import testing_module as test
import time

measures = [[], [], []]
numbers = [10, 100, 300, 500, 700]

def insertion_sort(array, x=0):
    start = time.time()
    for j in range(1, len(array)):
        key = array[j]
        i = j - 1
        while (i > -1) and key < array[i]:
            array[i + 1] = array[i]
            i = i - 1
        array[i + 1] = key
    end = time.time()
    measures[x].append(end - start)

test.test(insertion_sort, numbers, measures)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips and ideas how to improve my solution. ***Have a great day!***

Answer (score 2):

If I had to summarise this code, it would be: magical, spooky and puzzling. It works (which is a great start!) but you can make life easier on yourself and your maintainers.

You've invoked the root of all `eval`. Don't do this. There are many, many alternatives; the one I'll show uses simple polymorphism.

Many of your variable names need work. `element` is actually equivalent to your `array`; `numbers` is actually `lengths`; `accident` is really a sequence of test series generators.

Reduce your reliance on inferred figures and axes via the `plt.` functions, and instead use your figure and axis objects explicitly.

Avoid forcing a `plt.show()` inside of your `make_plot`; let the caller decide what to do with the figure.

Do not use `plot()`. For these data, `Optimistic` is basically flat. Use `loglog` instead.

Do not do timing and `measures` construction on the inside of your UUT (unit under test).

Do not call `test.test` from with the global namespace; use a `__main__` guard. Similarly, do not leave `measures` and `numbers` in the global namespace.

Introduce PEP484 type hints.

Avoid calling `reverse()`. Your generated test series are just as easily made via `range` calls, which will be more efficient and avoid mutation.

### Suggested

```
from random import randrange
from time import time
from typing import Callable, Iterable, List, Iterator, Sequence, Tuple

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Method = Callable[[List[int]], None]


class History:
    def __init__(self, lengths: Sequence[int], method: Method) -> None:
        self.measures: Tuple[float] = tuple(self.test(lengths, method))

    @staticmethod
    def make_data(length: int) -> Iterable[int]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def test(cls, lengths: Sequence[int], method: Method) -> Iterator[float]:
        for length in lengths:
            array = list(cls.make_data(length))
            start = time()
            method(array)
            end = time()
            yield end - start


class Optimistic(History):
    @staticmethod
    def make_data(length: int) -> Iterable[int]:
        return range(length)


class Pessimistic(History):
    @staticmethod
    def make_data(length: int) -> Iterable[int]:
        return range(length-1, -1, -1)


class Average(History):
    @staticmethod
    def make_data(length: int) -> Iterable[int]:
        for _ in range(length):
            yield randrange(1000)


def make_plot(
    lengths: Sequence[int],
    histories: Iterable[History],
    name: str,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for history in histories:
        ax.loglog(lengths, history.measures, label=type(history).__name__)
    ax.set_title(name)
    ax.legend()
    return fig


def test(
    method: Method,
    lengths: Sequence[int],
) -> Iterator[History]:
    for history_t in (Optimistic, Average, Pessimistic):
        yield history_t(lengths, method)


def insertion_sort(array: List[int]) -> None:
    for j in range(1, len(array)):
        key = array[j]
        i = j - 1
        while (i > -1) and key < array[i]:
            array[i + 1] = array[i]
            i = i - 1
        array[i + 1] = key


def main() -> None:
    lengths = (10, 100, 300, 500, 700)
    histories = test(method=insertion_sort, lengths=lengths)
    make_plot(
        lengths=lengths, histories=histories,
        name=insertion_sort.__name__,
    )
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Perhaps useful if OP is not used to working with figure/axes: [pyplot vs object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/#pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface)

Comment: I was testing it right now on the Python 3.9.8 and results are pretty weird... Everything's fine on 3.6.7